# CSS first-letter selection highlighting

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Is there any way to highlight the first character of an element that has the `::first-letter` pseudo-element applied to it?

I'm trying to give the user feedback in regards to a text selection. The text selected is being used for a Twitter plugin and works fine (i.e., the first-letter character *is* included); however, it doesn't appear as if the text can actually be highlighted.

Here's a link to a [CodePen example](http://codepen.io/doubleswirve/pen/LJEvm) and here is a screenshot to help demonstrate what I'm talking about:

[image]

I attempted to highlight the larger, red "S" but was unable to.

Any help is greatly appreciated and I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate. Thanks!

Comment: @doublewire its working in your link.

Comment: It definitely works for me on Firefox.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with WebKit, as both Chrome and Safari fail as the post describes.

Comment: Is there anything WebKit can get right?

Comment: Thanks guys (@Rex @BoltClock). Unfortunately (for this situation) WebKit is high priority.

Answer (score -2):

You can do something like this:

```
p:first-letter {
  float: left;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #333;
}

<p>This is your paragraph.</p>
```

I wrote about this a few years ago in an article entitled [Styling CSS First-Letter](http://kobashicomputing.com/styling-with-first-letter). There are more special case examples there.

Comment: How does any of that address the problem given in the question? Have you looked in the test case that was linked?

Comment: Thanks, but floating the pseudo-element doesn't seem to help with the text selection problem.